# How scalability of instances works

Tags: docker, microservices, scalable

What I have seen so far is that if an application does not support the actual load its possible to deploy a new instance of the same application and use a  load balancers to distribute the load between the two instances.

What I don't understand at this point is that how is possible to synchronize the information between both instances.

I.e. suppose that I have two instances A and B. I make a POST petition and the load balancer redirects me to A instance, this POST petition updates a map in A instance.

After that I make a GET petition to return the information in that map, and the load balancer redirects me to the B instance, this one will return a void map as the information is only in the A instance.

Maybe I don't understand this type of scalability.

Comment: It is your responsibility to make the data available in the way it's required.

Comment: So, in the case that I've exposed I will need to have a common DDBB?

Comment: ^ yes that's correct

Comment: You can also use a distributed cache like Hazelcast, or explicitly reroute requests like you do for Kafka, or use a sidecar that contains that logic, or or or.

Comment: Distributed applications and load balancing work with stateless applications . Which means you don't save state on particular machine but in shared data store , so any number of instances can share/Update data.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the type of data you are updating, that is whether it is **persistent data** (Data which remains even after powers goes) or **non-persistant data**. If you want something to be constant everywhere that is the instances share the same memory so for this you can use a database, where both the instances connect and atomically update and access the data.

If the map is just a constant you create temporarily in RAM, you can simply create a constant and that won't be shared by both instances.

E.g

**DATABASE** (shared memory)

DB -> Table -> mapcolumn - JSON Field (mapcolumn = {} #default value)

Req -> LoadBalancer -> INSTANCE A -> DB_Connection -> updates mapcolumn -> {'key': 'value'}
Req -> LoadBalancer -> INSTANCE B -> DB_Connection -> gets mapcolumn -> {'key': 'value'}

**RAM Constant**

Req -> LoadBalancer -> INSTANCE A -> sets mapcol constant -> mapcolumn = {'key': 'value'}

Req -> LoadBalancer -> INSTANCE B -> gets mapcolumn constant -> Null or None

Here the two instances don't use the database or shared memory.

Hopes this clears your doubt.